# Pass Seq as parameters in Scala non-vararg method

Tags: scala

I have a method in Scala that has a fixed number of parameters whose signature I cannot change:

```
def myMethod(a1: Int, a2: Int, a3: Int): Int = { /* stuff happens */ }
```

I also have an array `arr` with exactly the right number of elements as there are parameters in `myMethod`. If `myMethod` were a vararg method I could use the weird `: _*` notation to pass the array as parameters. I'd like to do something like

```
myMethod(/*some Scala magic with arr*/)
```

Is there a way to do that elegantly in Scala that does not require `myMethod` to be vararg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the closest you can come to that is to deconstruct your array in a step before invoking your method:

```
val Array(a1, a2, a3) = arr
myMethod(a1, a2, a3)
```

Comment: OK, that's cool. I was just hoping that there might be some obscure feature that would enable this... Thanks!

Comment: Beware that this will throw a `MatchError` if the array does not contain exactly 3 elements.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you maybe maybe can't change a signature but you could add an overload through implicit conversion

```
class A {
  def myMethod(a1: Int, a2: Int, a3: Int): Int = 5
}

implicit class ExA(self: A) extends AnyVal {
  def myMethod(arr: Array[Int]): Int = {
    val Array(a1, a2, a3) = arr
    self.myMethod(a1, a2, a3)
  }
}
```

And then you simply can pass your array, if it is not 3 elements long you will get an error in runtime.

```
scala> (new A).myMethod(Array(1, 2, 3))
res2: Int = 5
```

Without any extra knowledge compiler can't be as sure as you about the size of array and thus there doesn't seem to be a way to just expand some arbitrary array into 3 arguments and put it into a function.